# detecting lines and their positions in an image

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I simply want to find a line in my image and its details like the starting pixel and length.I have looked into many methods but am getting only more and more confused. My image is as simple as

[image: something drawn by me]

My goal is to detect the line and draw something like a ball or square on it.
I am using openCV and trying to do this on android.

Answer (score 1):

You could use OpenCV [Contours](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) to segment the line and

- Use  [boundingRect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#boundingrect) to find the staring and end  points of line
- Use [arcLength](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#arclength) to find the length of line